# pdf file is creating and downloading ..but cant open as it shows can't open file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

This is my code..

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Export()
    {
        GridView grid = new GridView();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        var ItemsFromDb = lst.FetchDataFromList(Session["userId"].ToString()).ToList();
        if (ItemsFromDb.Count != 0)
        {
            grid.DataSource = ItemsFromDb;
            grid.DataBind();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "Attachment;filename=" + "Members_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyy") + ".pdf");
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.Charset = "";
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            grid.RenderControl(hw);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "Sorry.. No data to export.";
            return View();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("UserDetails","EmployeeLocation");
    }
```

This code works perfectly fine for creating and downloading excel format by only changing the types as `.xls` and `"application/ms-excel"`

but the is side the pdf the datas are not loading...

Comment: What does _"the datas are not loading"_ mean, exactly?

Comment: means the datas of ItemsFromDb are not there in the pdf file which is being created..

Comment: You can't write HTML and call it PDF. If you want some HTML to be rendered as a PDF file, look into a library like Rotativa.